# Empty ShapeLength when running Insert Cursor for Polyline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, cursor, polyline-creation

I'm looking to create a new feature class using only selected data from a source feature class. I can get this to work but the ShapeLength field is 0 when I run this script and therefore the feature class has no spatial data. All the other fields are properly filled.

I think I'm missing a step or an array or something but the data is coming right from the source feature class not a list so I don't know how to get it in.

```
import arcpy, os, zipfile
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "Database Connections\\CNTM_MAC_GIS(EPRD-SHS12-LTR,62246).sde"
env.overwriteOutput=True

# Setting Sources

    #spatial reference
sr1 = "GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]];-400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119521E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"


BreadSource= "//natn4/NAT_shrdata/MAC/GIS/Data/GPS/Geodatabases/GPS_data.gdb/All_2018_GPS_data"
BreadTarget=arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(GDBLocation, "GPS_Routes", "POLYLINE", BreadSource, "", "",sr1 ) # set output location

dsc = arcpy.Describe(BreadSource)
fields = dsc.fields



fieldnames = [field.name for field in fields if field.name != dsc.OIDFieldName]
#fieldnames = [field.name for field in fields]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(BreadSource,fieldnames, "Date_dt > date "+ "'" + yyyy + '-' + smm + '-'+ sd + " 00:00:00' AND Date_dt < date "+ "'" + yyyy + '-' + emm + '-'+ ed + " 23:59:59'") as sCur: #add sql where statement to extract subset of data
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(BreadTarget,fieldnames) as iCur:
        for row in sCur:
            iCur.insertRow(row)

del sCur
del iCur
```

Comment: There are many potential problems with pasting one row to another without verifying the equivalence of the spatial reference. Given the `with` blocks, the `del` directives are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use cursors to copy selected features:

```
# make a feature layer from the source data
arcpy.makeFeatureLayer_management(BreadSource, "BreadLayer")

# select features in the layer
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("BreadLayer", "NEW_SELECTION", "Date_dt > date "+ "'" + yyyy + '-' + smm + '-'+ sd + " 00:00:00' AND Date_dt < date "+ "'" + yyyy + '-' + emm + '-'+ ed + " 23:59:59'" )

# set an output target
BreadTarget = "path\to\your\gdb\GPS_Routes"

# copy the selected features
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(BreadLayer, BreadTarget)
```

Comment: Thank you I was over complicating due do a datebase issue where I could only select 1000 features at a time but luckily this dataset is not on that same database. Thank you! If I did need to use curcors, is there a way to do it with Polylines?

Comment: My guess is that much like you skip the OID, you should also skip the geometry field and instead use the "SHAPE@" magic token.